# Update column data in one table when id in other table is created

Tags: c#, sql

I have two tables: tblInvoice and tblAppointment
I want tblInvoice to be automatically updated when a new Appointment is created (the Appointment number is created automatically)
I've tried everything I've read on here and nothing works so I have to keep on deleting what's already in the Invoice table and using an Insert stored procedure to fill it up.  How can I get it to update without duplicating the Appointment numbers whenever a new Appointment is created?  Need code for the stored procedure and c# to put into my save button on the add Appointment page to make it work. Thanks.

Comment: the column in common is AppointmentNo

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a stored procedure to create the new entry in the Appointment table?

At the end of that stored procedure, you need to find the entry in the Invoice table you want to update. If such an entry exists, you want to update it. In order to find this out, there has to be some sort of relationship between your two tables. I cannot know the relationship unless you share your data model with us.

Please share your stored proc and table definitions.

Comment: No the entries are made via windows forms data entry.

Comment: The invoice table has InvoiceNo (Primary Key) and AppointmentNo(Foreign Key).  This is the stored procedure I have written but it doesn't work:CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sproc_updateInvoiceTable]
 as
 update tblInvoice
 set tblInvoice.AppointmentNo=tblAppointment.AppointmentNo
 from tblInvoice inner join tblAppointment on tblInvoice.AppointmentNo=tblAppointment.AppointmentNo
 
RETURN 0  the insert one does, but as I said, I have to keep deleting the data, running the proc and then reopening VS which is silly!

Answer (score 0):

Create a trigger which will update tblInvoice after any insert to tblAppointment

Comment: how do i do that?